# XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed Build failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I am trying to use XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed in order to test if a specific exception was thrown, but the build fails when I try to use it.  I am not sure why.

Below is the method in my XCTestCase

```
- (void)testExceptionWasThrown {
    XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed([MyClassName throwThisWithName:@"abc"], NSException, @"coolExcption") //When I comment this out the Build passes.
}
```

....

Here is the Class implementation

```
@interface MyClassName : NSObject 
    + (void)throwThisWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end

@implementation MyClassName
    + (void)throwThisWithName:(NSString *)name {
        NSException* exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"coolException" reason:name userInfo:nil];
        @throw exception;  
    }
@end
```

Comment: Can you paste the build error?

Comment: There is no Console output.  Xcode 6 simply shows that splash image that says "Build Failed"